# Proving A ~ CB if A = BC and 0 is not an eigenvalue of B

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to prove that, if A, B, and C are $n \times n$ matrices, $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $B$, and $A = BC$ that $A$ is similar to $CB$

I know that I have to get to $A = SCBS^{-1}$ for some $n \times x$ matrix $S$. and I think that somehow $B^{-1}C^{-1}$ is involved so that $(B^{-1}C^{-1})^{-1}$ = $CB$, but I am at a loss for where to start to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
A & = BC\\
B^{-1}A & = C\\
B^{-1}AB & = CB.
\end{align*}
Thus $A$ is similar to $CB$.

Comment: The crucial piece here is that $B$ is invertible.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Ahh, so that's where $0$ not being an eigenvalue of $B$ comes into play?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{} $

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing that the invertibility of $B$ or $C$ is essential. 
Let
$$
B = \pmatrix{ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 }, \quad
C = \pmatrix{ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0 }.
$$
Then we find
$$
BC = \pmatrix{ 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 }, \quad
CB =\pmatrix{ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 },
$$
hence $BC$ and $CB$ are not similar, although having the same spectrum.

Comment: For a $2x2$ example one can take $B=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}$, $C=\pmatrix{1&1\\-1&-1}$.